# How to remove someone who is connected to my facebook page using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a Facebook application and I want to remove someone who is connected to my Facebook page using graph API. At the same I want to remove his like from my Facebook page. So initially if my page like is 100 and after removing the user it should be 99. How can I do this using graph API? Can I achieve this by blocking the user?

Thanks

Comment: Facebook let's you remove likes?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra That is my question. Can I remove the likes from my Facebook page? That is my Facebook page should not exceed more than 1000 likes.

Comment: I've honestly never heard of a way to do that. If anyone figures that one out I'd be fascinated to see how, but AFAIK you can't remove likes from a page, only ban users. In terms of banning users from the graph api, that I am not sure of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to remove a like of a Facebook Page, neither from the user's side nor the page's side